# Showing Observable<any[ ]> return type within HTML

Tags: angular

New to Angular 2 so maybe a bit basic.

I have a Service function getMedia which is an Observable of type any[] returns this information to the component upon subscription:

[image: getMedia return data]

Essentially, this is an Array of Objects so in my components I wrote this:

```
export class RecommendationFeedComponent implements OnInit {

  result:Array<Object>=[];

  constructor(private feedService: FeedService, private authService: AuthService,
              private auth: FirebaseAuth, public af: AngularFire) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(
        (user) => {
            if (user) {
              this.feedService.getMedia(user.auth.email)
                  .subscribe(result => this.result = result);
              console.log(this.result);
            }
    })

  }
```

The console returns empty so I am not sure how I can use this to display the data on HTML.

Changed component and template:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FeedService} from "../shared/model/feed.service";
import {RestaurantMedia} from "../shared/model/restaurantMedia";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "../shared/security/auth.service";
import {FirebaseAuth, AngularFire} from "angularfire2/index";


@Component({
  selector: 'recommendation-feed',
  templateUrl: './recommendation-feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recommendation-feed.component.css']
})
export class RecommendationFeedComponent implements OnInit {
  //Medias = [];
  //RestaurantMedias$: Observable<any[]>;
  result:Array<Object>=[];


  constructor(private feedService: FeedService, private authService: AuthService,
              private auth: FirebaseAuth, public af: AngularFire) { }

  ngOnInit() {

        this.af
        .auth
        .flatMap(user => this.feedService.getMedia(user.auth.email))
        .subscribe(result => {
               this.result = result;
            //  console.log(this.result);
            })



  }

}
```

// HTML template code below this

```
<tr class *ngFor="let media of (result)">
   <td>
     <img src={{media.data.images.standard_resolution.url}} height="100" width="100">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what's the errorr?

Comment: My bad, it works as you mentioned. I had another error. Thanks for help! Upvoted.

Comment: That's alright then, is it accepted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

subscribe is asyncroinous , so you're console.log should be inside it otherwise it'll be called even before the subscribe function is called.

So to fix it :

Change :

```
         this.feedService.getMedia(user.auth.email)
              .subscribe(result => this.result = result);
          console.log(this.result);
```

To

```
    this.feedService.getMedia(user.auth.email)
              .subscribe(result => {
                      this.result = result
                     console.log(this.result);

               });
```

---

And by the way, here's a nicer way :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.af
        .auth
        .flatMap(user => this.feedService.getMedia(user.auth.email))
        .subscribe(result => {
               this.result = result);
              console.log(this.result
         });
```

And if you only want to show the result in html without doing anything with it , you can use async pipe :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.result = 
      this.af
        .auth
        .flatMap(user => this.feedService.getMedia(user.auth.email)) // no subscribe
```

And then inside your template :

```
<div >
       {{result | async | json }}
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Milad. Thanks for response! The template html didn't quite work and showed error, however when I wrote this this data showed up

<tr class *ngFor="let media of (result)">
   <td>
     <img src={{media.data.images.standard_resolution.url}} height="100" width="100">
  </td>
</tr>

Comment: Share your component and it's template

Comment: Added it to question